# Docker UDP port support?

Tags: udp, ip, docker

I have been testing as in the environment below:

[image: my current lab]

everything worked well, except i can not contact
UDP Port in docker container, please advice me.

also currently i use "ip netns exec" to set IP address any easy way to fix IP address in container?

thank for advance
Prasong P.

Comment: my current lab.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Yki.jpg

Answer (score 7):

You can expose UDP ports adding `/udp` suffix. Example:

`docker run -p 127.0.0.1:53:5353/udp <image> <cmd>`

Answer (score 2):

It is in the docs, here is an extract from

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/

You can also bind UDP ports by adding a trailing /udp. For example:

$ sudo docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000/udp training/webapp python app.py

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec) command to do the `ip netns exec` for you.