# sending logs to fluentd from python script via syslog protocol

Tags: python, fluentd, syslog

I have started the fluentd server with docker.My fluentd configuration is

```
<source>
  @type syslog
  port 514
  bind 0.0.0.0
  tag system
</source>

<match **>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

The command I used to start the `fluentd` server is

```
docker run -p 514:514 -v $(pwd)/tmp:/fluentd/etc fluent/fluentd:edge-debian -c /fluentd/etc/fluentd.conf
```

It starts the server successfully and I get the log

```
2023-09-20 16:05:18 +0000 [info]: init supervisor logger path=nil rotate_age=nil rotate_size=nil
2023-09-20 16:05:18 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluentd.conf"
2023-09-20 16:05:18 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.16.2'
2023-09-20 16:05:18 +0000 [warn]: define <match fluent.**> to capture fluentd logs in top level is deprecated. Use <label @FLUENT_LOG> instead
2023-09-20 16:05:18 +0000 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <source>
    @type syslog
    port 514
    bind "0.0.0.0"
    tag "system"
  </source>
  <match **>
    @type stdout
  </match>
</ROOT>
2023-09-20 16:05:18 +0000 [info]: starting fluentd-1.16.2 pid=7 ruby="3.1.4"
2023-09-20 16:05:18 +0000 [info]: spawn command to main:  cmdline=["/usr/local/bin/ruby", "-Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit", "/usr/local/bundle/bin/fluentd", "-c", "/fluentd/etc/fluentd.conf", "--plugin", "/fluentd/plugins", "--under-supervisor"]
2023-09-20 16:05:19 +0000 [info]: #0 init worker0 logger path=nil rotate_age=nil rotate_size=nil
2023-09-20 16:05:19 +0000 [info]: adding match pattern="**" type="stdout"
2023-09-20 16:05:19 +0000 [info]: adding source type="syslog"
2023-09-20 16:05:19 +0000 [warn]: #0 define <match fluent.**> to capture fluentd logs in top level is deprecated. Use <label @FLUENT_LOG> instead
2023-09-20 16:05:19 +0000 [info]: #0 starting fluentd worker pid=16 ppid=7 worker=0
2023-09-20 16:05:19 +0000 [info]: #0 listening syslog socket on 0.0.0.0:514 with udp
2023-09-20 16:05:19 +0000 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now running worker=0
2023-09-20 16:05:19.058192424 +0000 fluent.info: {"pid":16,"ppid":7,"worker":0,"message":"starting fluentd worker pid=16 ppid=7 worker=0"}
2023-09-20 16:05:19.058414751 +0000 fluent.info: {"message":"listening syslog socket on 0.0.0.0:514 with udp"}
2023-09-20 16:05:19.059112948 +0000 fluent.info: {"worker":0,"message":"fluentd worker is now running worker=0"}
```

I have wrote the simple python script to test the connection which is as follows

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import socket

if __name__ == "__main__":
    syslogger = logging.getLogger('SyslogLogger')
    handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=("0.0.0.0", 514), facility=19, socktype=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    syslogger.addHandler(handler)
    syslogger.info("Hello World")
```

Script runs without any error but I don't get any log on the on the fluentd.

Server and script both are on a local machine.

Comment: Use [syslog](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/syslog) input plugin instead of [http](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/http).

Comment: I just observed that the config you're showing in the first part has `http` source but in the logs the loaded config is showing `syslog` source. And, the port you're using with `docker` is 9880, not 514. For a simpler setup, you can test this on your local machine first and then move on to docker to emulate the same.

Comment: Sorry yeah I fixed all those those things `http` -> `syslog` and using correct port in docker container. I copied the wrong config file while creating the question. Still the issue is the same.

Comment: Right. Is your Python script able to send logs to your local syslog? Have you tested it?

Comment: Just tested your script on Ubuntu 21.04 and it doesn't work as is. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3969772/7670262 for the required changes to make it work. After setting log level and the `address='/dev/log'`, it works for me for local syslog.

Comment: Thanks but I found the actual problem and updated the answer.

Comment: Good to hear that. FYI: The script on the local machine was not working because the existing configuration for UDP was disabled by default. After enabling that and setting the required minimum log level worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution issue was with docker
adding `/udp` suffix while exposing the port solved my problem.
[Docker UDP port support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223786/docker-udp-port-support)